# Changing the update strategy on a CoreOS machine with a maintenance window

Tags: update, coreos

I want to change the update strategy on a running CoreOS machine with a  maintenance window described [here](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/update-strategies.html), which is different what was asked [before in a similar direction](https://serverfault.com/questions/658925/change-update-strategy-of-coreos-machine).

It is clear to me that this can be done through a cloud-config file. But how can I do it on a running machine, that it persists? Where are the files to make this change (e.g. /etc/coreos/update.conf) particular to set the maintenance window?

Answer (score 1):

[The CoreOS documentation](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/cloud-config-locations.html) lists various places to look for your cloud-config file, depending on how and where the CoreOS instance is provisioned. Since I'm working through this problem myself, I added a cloud-config file to one of the locations, `/var/lib/coreos-install/user_data`, with the following:

```
#cloud-config
coreos:
  locksmith:
    window-start: Fri 10:00
    window-length: 2h
```

When I rebooted the instance I looked at `systemctl status locksmithd` and it looks like my config took hold

```
ip-172-23-109-250 core # systemctl status locksmithd
● locksmithd.service - Cluster reboot manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/locksmithd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/system/locksmithd.service.d
           └─20-cloudinit.conf
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-03-02 00:36:48 UTC; 1min 37s ago
 Main PID: 878 (locksmithd)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 32768)
   CGroup: /system.slice/locksmithd.service
           └─878 /usr/lib/locksmith/locksmithd

Mar 02 00:36:48 ip-172-23-109-250.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Started Cluster reboot manager.
Mar 02 00:36:49 ip-172-23-109-250.us-west-2.compute.internal locksmithd[878]: Reboot window start is "Fri 10:00" and length is "2h"
Mar 02 00:36:49 ip-172-23-109-250.us-west-2.compute.internal locksmithd[878]: Next window begins at 2018-03-02 10:00:00 +0000 UTC and ends at 2018-03-02 12:00:00 +0000 UTC
Mar 02 00:36:49 ip-172-23-109-250.us-west-2.compute.internal locksmithd[878]: locksmithd starting currentOperation="UPDATE_STATUS_IDLE" strategy="reboot"
```

Since I'm provisioning my CoreOS instance with kops, which reserves the Ec2 metadata cloud-config file location for its own shell script, I had to add this additional space for my own cloud-config. It appears that CoreOS is able to pull both configs in.

Alternatively, you can declare your own cloud-config path with `sudo coreos-cloudinit --from-file=/home/core/cloud-config.yaml`